# Jenkins - Add custom webpage to Jenkins

Tags: mongodb, jenkins

Management has given me a task to add a link(ex. under "People" link) and display a table w/ data from a DB(MongoDB). The user will be then able to insert/update the table and have it saved to the DB.

Using HTML/CSS/JS I am capable to doing it but I don't know how to modify jenkins to do so. I've looked for plugins like "Simple Theme" but from what I saw it only updates CSS and JS of Jenkins UI. I'm new to Jenkins and really have not idea where to start.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: If you just want to host your own web page via Jenkins, I think the simplest is to put the files under `$JENKINS_HOME/userContent` - anything in this folder is accessible from the web interface (`http://myjenkinsserver:8080/userContent/`)

Comment: @AkosBannerth I was able to host a webpage =] so that is great. But I'm looking to intergrate it with the jernkins homepage rather than host a seperate page. I'll see what I can do with this but it looks like I will probably end up making a plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To **customize a jenkins plugin** of your own is a graceful solution but complicated for someone who is new to jenkins.

1. create a new **jenkins-plugin project** and need to be familiar with java/maven before.
2. create **a java subclass** which implements **hudson.model.RootAction**.
3. create **index.jelly** which display the table data from the DB and need to learn jelly before.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping there was a simpler way but after researching everything seems to be pointing to this direction.

Comment: just curious, Jenkins seems not easy to use, not flexiable, why it is so popular?